# Djnago QuerySet: distinct() work for one field, but don't work for enother

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have QuerySet with two fields:

````
```Python
print(products_mtm)

<QuerySet 
[
{'fk_products': 2653, 'fk_classes': 20}, 
{'fk_products': 2653, 'fk_classes': 23}, 
{'fk_products': 2653, 'fk_classes': 29}, 
{'fk_products': 2654, 'fk_classes': 20}, 
{'fk_products': 2654, 'fk_classes': 21}, 
{'fk_products': 2654, 'fk_classes': 24}, 
{'fk_products': 2655, 'fk_classes': 20},
{'fk_products': 2655, 'fk_classes': 25},
....]

print(products_mtm.values_list('fk_products').distinct())
````

<QuerySet [(2653,), (2654,), (2655,),...] # It's OK!

````
print(products_mtm.values_list('fk_classes').distinct())
<QuerySet [(20,), (23,), (29,), (20,), (21,), (24,), (20,) (25,)...] #It does't DISTINCT it is  full values_list of the 'fk_classes'

```
````

Comment: Share your models, please

Comment: there is no need in the models. ts asked to display distinct fk_classes, it seems that distinct is applied to the queryset and not to the value list. There is note in the docs about it: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#distinct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the problem due to sorting. `products_mtm` had `order_by('fk_products')` above.
[docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#distinct](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) – alv2017

I'm free to reject this `order_by` where - and all `distinct()` works all right. But if ordering is nessesary, simply way for me - just to use `set(products_mtm.values_list('fk_classes'))` instead of `distinct()`.
*(May be it`s not native for Django QuerySets, but it works properly.)*